# Specify delimiter in collect_set function in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I want to add a delimiter in the collect_set function which I'm using in Spark SQL.
If it is not available, please let me know how can I achieve it in any alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`concat,concat_ws,collect_set`** to specify delimiter in **Spark SQL**.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("a",1),("a",3),("b",2)).toDF("id","sa")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql("""select concat('[', //concat with opening bracket
                            concat_ws(';', //custom delimiter
                                        collect_set(sa)),
                                                        concat(']') //concat with closing bracket
                            ) as cnct_deli 
                    from tmp 
                group by id""").show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---------+
|cnct_deli|
+---------+
|      [2]|
|    [1;3]|
+---------+
```